# pointer conversions char* to int* without copying

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a file laid out as such:

```
Offset   Type            Value         [meaning]
0000     32 bit integer  60000         count of data
0004     32 bit integer  32            width
0008     32 bit integer  32            height
0012     byte            1             data; ext.
```

I read in the data by quickly dumping the file contents to a string.

Due to the size of the file, and the nature of the data and how its used id like to try to avoid copying it all over the place.

So I wish to use pointers to the data, to save time, but I cant get them to work quite right.

Id like to do something like this:

```
std::string mydata;
dumpdata("myfile.bin",mydata); //dumps data to reference string.
uint32_t* count = (uint32_t*)&mydata[4]; //32 bit integer.
```

I know i'm forgetting a cast or something but I cant figure out what it is.
What I tried didn't work.

To make this clear. I do not want to copy. I just want count to point to that area and treat it like an uint32_t even tho its an array of bytes.

This is probably a super easy questions, but its one of them "google thinks i'm trying to convert ascii" things, and i'm not.

I expect if the data is: 00002710H I will get the uint 10000. Instead I get 270,991,360

Comment: If you have a new enough compiler then consider [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

Comment: By the way, you never mention what your problem with the cast you show is? What do you expect `*count` to be after that assignment? What is it really?

Comment: I get 270,991,360. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Well that's equal to `0x10270000` which seems somewhat right, depending on [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of course. Oh and while you can store arbitrary binary data in a `std::string` object, I suggest you use `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead.

Comment: Ah crap. I just realized that. So my input is in big edian, and my system is using little edian. No wonder. Now i need to figure out how to get it to swap without copying.

Comment: @StevenVenham: You’re making work for yourself: just [do the math](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html?m=1) rather than trying both type punning and byte swapping.  The compiler will do this efficiently [even if it has to swap bytes](https://godbolt.org/g/d7du4k).

Comment: @Steven - You are just trying too hard. A pointer is *at least* as large as an integer, perhaps twice as big on a 64-bit computer. So instead of copying an integer you copy a pointer, which might be **more** work.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want count to point to that area and treat it like an uint32_t even tho its an array of bytes.

This is not possible in Standard C++ (nor C for that matter).

If your intent is to read the data, one solution would be to write:

```
uint32_t get_count(std::string const& mydata)
{
    uint32_t x;
    std::memcpy(&x, &mydata[4], 4);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: @StevenVenham maybe on your compiler for now... the C++ language is defined by a standards document which says your technique is not supported